# Multiple choice question on $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^2, f(x,y)=({x\over 1+x+y},{y\over 1+x+y})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x+y\neq -1\}$

$f:A\to\mathbb{R}^2, f(x,y)=({x\over 1+x+y},{y\over 1+x+y})$,Then

1. Jacobian matrix of $f$ does not vanish on $A$
2. $f$ is infinitely differentiable on $A$
3. $f$ is injective on $A$
4. $f(A)=\mathbb{R}^2$

I have calculated $J={(x+y+2)(y-x)\over (x+y+1)^2}$, It will vanish only when $y=x$ or $x+y=-2$ but clearly they are in $A^c$, so $1$ is true.

Yes, $f$ is infinitely differentiable  which I understand from the expression but which result I  have to use to  conclude that or how?

$f$ is injective  as Non vanishing Jacobian

$f$ is not surjective as $({1\over 2},1)$ has no pre-image in $A$
Shall be glad to have reply

Comment: What is $f(-1,-2)$? Regarding $1$ what's $J$ supposed to be? The jacobian matrix is a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: Perhaps OP is conflating matrix and determinant.

Comment: Oh Yes, I  thought they are asking whether determinant of the Jacobian matrix vanishes, anyway the matrix also does not vanish on $A$

Comment: @la Bella Noiseuse... can u show how u find jacobian matrix of this function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Injection and Bijection of the function $f(x,y)=(\frac{x}{1+x+y},\frac{y}{1+x+y}).$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576602/injection-and-bijection-of-the-function-fx-y-fracx1xy-fracy1xy)