# Injection and Bijection of the function $f(x,y)=(\frac{x}{1+x+y},\frac{y}{1+x+y}).$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:x+y\neq-1 \}$

Define $$f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$$ by $$f(x,y)=(\frac{x}{1+x+y},\frac{y}{1+x+y}).$$ I have to prove that the the function $f$ is one one but not onto. It is clear that $f$ is continuously differentiable but Inverse map theorem gives locally injectiveness of $f.$ How to show that $f$ is one one but not onto?

For onto i think $(u,v)$ such that $u+v-1=0$ does not have pre image. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write out the condition for $f(x,y)=(A,B):$

$$\eqalign{
x&=A(x+y+1)\\
y&=B(x+y+1)
}$$

$$\eqalign{
(A-1)x+Ay+A&=0\\
Bx+(B-1)y+B&=0
}$$

This is a linear system with determinant $1-A-B$ so it does *not* have a unique solution if and only if $A+B=1.$

$f$ is not onto because it never reaches the point (A=1/2,B=1/2).

$f$ is one-to-one because whenever the determinant of the system is 0 it is unsolvable: put $B=1-A,$ then

$$\eqalign{
(A-1)x+Ay+A&=0\\
(1-A)x-Ay+(1-A)&=0
}$$

The sum of these two equations gives $1=0.$

Comment: Your answer seems to be nice one...but how to compare with linear system?

Comment: Please explane me little more ...

Comment: Thanks a lot...now i get your solution...thanks for your precise time.

Comment: Just one question: can we conclude non-vanishing jacobian implies one-to-one?

Comment: For a general differentiable mapping the injectiveness is only local, but for a linear mapping: yes, global bijection. In the latter context it is not usually called a Jacobian, but just the determinant of the system (see your linear algebra course notes).

Comment: ok thanks a lot...